# SQL Question Involving Number of Challenges Solved

Tags: mysql

The following question is based on a HackerRank question [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/challenges/problem). It is written as follows:

> Julia asked her students to create some coding challenges. Write a
>   query to print the hacker_id, name, and the total number of challenges
>   created by each student. Sort your results by the total number of
>   challenges in descending order. If more than one student created the
>   same number of challenges, then sort the result by hacker_id. If more
>   than one student created the same number of challenges and the count
>   is less than the maximum number of challenges created, then exclude
>   those students from the result.

In the challenge, I submitted the following, but for some reason there is a syntax error. What is the problem?

```
 select h.hacker_id
     , h.name
     , count(c.challenge_id) count1 
  from hackers h 
  join challenges c
    on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id 
 where h.hacker_id not in  
          (select hh.hacker_id 
             from hackers hh 
             join challenges cc
               on cc.hacker_id = hh.hacker_id 
             join 
                ( select hhh.hacker_id
                       , count(ccc.challenge_id) count2 
                    from hackers hhh 
                    join challenges ccc
                      on ccc.hacker_id = hhh.hacker_id 
                   group 
                      by hhh.hacker_id 
                  having count(ccc.challenge_id) < 
                              (select max(count2) 
                                 from 
                                    ( select count(cc.challenge_id) count2 
                                        from hackers hh 
                                        join challenges cc
                                          on hh.hacker_id = cc.hacker_id
                                    ) a
                               ) b
                ) t 
               on t.hacker_id <> hh.hacker_id 
          ) c 
      group 
         by h.hacker_id
          , h.name
      order 
         by count(c.challenge_id)
          , h.hacker_id desc
```

Comment: Have you tried an online sql validator? It points me to your `b`

Comment: Try removing the alias `b`

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the validity of what follows, but it is at least syntactically valid...

```
select c.hacker_id
     , h.name 
     , count(c.hacker_id) c_count
  from hackers h
  join challenges c 
    on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
 group 
    by c.hacker_id
     , h.name
having c_count = 
   ( SELECT MAX(temp1.cnt) 
       from 
          ( SELECT COUNT(hacker_id) cnt
              from challenges
             group 
                by hacker_id
          ) temp1
    ) 
    or c_count in 
        (select t.cnt
           from 
              ( select count(*) cnt 
                  from challenges
                 group 
                    by hacker_id
              ) t
          group 
             by t.cnt
         having count(t.cnt) = 1)
          order 
             by c_count DESC
              , c.hacker_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems like most solutions do a union. It there a way of to "subtract" off the part that I don't need as I was doing above? Or is it more complicated?

Comment: I tend to avoid these challenges unless the data set and desired result is included in the SO question, so I'll pass (which might just be code for 'it's too difficult for me')

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the below two methods and they both worked fine. Just different approach to the question.

/*
Working platform:- MySQL
*/
/*

```
SELECT H.HACKER_ID, 
       H.NAME, 
       COUNT(C.CHALLENGE_ID) AS C_COUNT
FROM HACKERS H
JOIN CHALLENGES C ON C.HACKER_ID = H.HACKER_ID
GROUP BY H.HACKER_ID, H.NAME
HAVING C_COUNT = 
    (SELECT COUNT(C2.CHALLENGE_ID) AS C_MAX
     FROM CHALLENGES AS C2
     GROUP BY C2.HACKER_ID 
     ORDER BY C_MAX DESC LIMIT 1)
OR C_COUNT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT C_COMPARE AS C_UNIQUE
     FROM (SELECT H2.HACKER_ID, 
                  H2.NAME, 
                  COUNT(CHALLENGE_ID) AS C_COMPARE
           FROM HACKERS H2
           JOIN CHALLENGES C ON C.HACKER_ID = H2.HACKER_ID
           GROUP BY H2.HACKER_ID, H2.NAME) COUNTS
     GROUP BY C_COMPARE
     HAVING COUNT(C_COMPARE) = 1)
ORDER BY C_COUNT DESC, H.HACKER_ID;
```

*/

/*
The above is the original code
The following is the code I suggest
The idea is instead of looking for unique counts, you eliminate counts that are not unique
Credit: https://medium.com/jen-li-chen-in-data-science/hackerrank-sql-bd819dfcaee7
*/

```
SELECT c.hacker_id, h.name, count(c.challenge_id) AS cnt 
FROM Hackers AS h JOIN Challenges AS c ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
GROUP BY c.hacker_id, h.name 
HAVING cnt = (SELECT count(c1.challenge_id) FROM Challenges AS c1 GROUP BY c1.hacker_id 
              ORDER BY count(*) desc limit 1) or
cnt NOT IN (SELECT count(c2.challenge_id) FROM Challenges AS c2 GROUP BY c2.hacker_id 
            HAVING c2.hacker_id <> c.hacker_id)
ORDER BY cnt DESC, c.hacker_id;
```